# Moved Laravel project from Apache to Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, laravel-5

I have deployed my laravel app on a centos server and I had to add below mentioned lines in httpd.conf to make it work

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/ezschedular2/public">
  Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

We have decided to use `nginx` now, what is the alternate of these lines? I have to add alternate of these lines on `default.conf` in folder `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

Answer (score 0):

This is my nginx config for Laravel. Change variable suit your need

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name YOURSERVERNAME_OR_IP;
    root YOUR_PATH_TO_LARAVEL_PUBLIC_FOLDER;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```